# create inherited childwindow in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a ChildWindow.  In this childwindow, I have added properties that link to a textblock, and a contentpresenter.  I want to use this childwindow as the base class, and have other child windows inherit from it.  When they inherit from it, I want their content area (i.e. the area inside the "layoutroot" grid to be placed in the parent childwindow's contentcontrol.  I am able to make this happen if I programatically create the content and assign it, but I cannot get it to work in the XAML.

Could someone give me an idea how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute(v=VS.95).aspx